# Is there a way to directly configure an 8086 processor to directly send data to 8255 PPI without use of a latch?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, proteus

I am using emu8086 emulation software and Proteus in order to display data on an LCD. 
My task is simple, to just simply display a string defined in the assembly code onto the LCD in proteus. 
The issue however, is that I want to be able to directly interface only the 8086 to the 8255 PPI which will then send the data to be displayed on the LCD, but I don't know how to do so. 
Any tutorials/reference materials I see online involve use of latches to demultiplex the address lines.

**The schematic**: 
[image: proteus schematic]
**The assembly code**:

```
DATA SEGMENT
;variables to keep track of port data
    PORTA_VAL DB 0
    PORTB_VAL DB 0
    PORTC_VAL DB 0
    
;sample string
    welcome DB  "Hello Namibia! This is the message.$" 
    
    
;port addresses  
    PORTA EQU 00H   ;PORTA IS CONNECTED TO THE D7-D0
    PORTB EQU 02H   ;PORTB0 IS RW, PORTB1 IS RS, PORTB2 IS EN
    PORTC EQU 04H
    PCW   EQU 06H   ;PORT FOR IO CONTROL
    
ENDS

STACK SEGMENT
    DW   128  DUP(0)
ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
START:
; set segment registers: 
    MOV AX, DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX  
    
;define IO ports
    MOV DX,PCW
    MOV AL,10000000B   ;to make all ports output
    OUT DX,AL  
    
    ;XOR AL,AL
    ;BEGIN:
    ;   CALL OUT_B
    ;   MOV CX,5FFFH
    ;   CALL DELAY
    ;   INC AL
    ;JMP BEGIN 
    
    ;TEST_L:        
    ;   NOT AL
    ;   CALL OUT_C
    ;   MOV CX,50
    ;   @LTOP:
    ;   LOOP @LTOP
    ;JMP TEST_L
        
    ;MOV CX,500
    ;CALL DELAY
    
    
       
    CALL LCD_INIT   
    ;MOV AL,1H      ;debug marker
    ;CALL OUT_C 
    
    
    
    MOV DL,1
    MOV DH,1
    CALL LCD_SET_CUR
    ;MOV AL,2H      ;debug marker
    ;CALL OUT_C
    
    
    MOV DL,1
    MOV DH,1
    CALL LCD_SET_CUR
    LEA SI,welcome
    CALL LCD_PRINTSTR
    
        
  
    HLT
;end of main procedure





;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                                    ;
;       LCD function library.        ;
;                                    ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
PROC DELAY
;input: CX, this value controls the delay. CX=50 means 1ms
;output: none
    JCXZ @DELAY_END
    @DEL_LOOP:
    LOOP @DEL_LOOP  
    @DELAY_END:
    RET
ENDP DELAY



; LCD initialization
PROC LCD_INIT
;input: none
;output: none

;make RS=En=RW=0
    MOV AL,0
    CALL OUT_B
;delay 20ms
    MOV CX,1000
    CALL DELAY
;reset sequence
    MOV AH,30H
    CALL LCD_CMD
    MOV CX,250
    CALL DELAY
    
    MOV AH,30H
    CALL LCD_CMD
    MOV CX,50
    CALL DELAY
    
    MOV AH,30H
    CALL LCD_CMD
    MOV CX,500
    CALL DELAY
    
;function set
    MOV AH,38H
    CALL LCD_CMD
    
    MOV AH,0CH
    CALL LCD_CMD
    
    MOV AH,01H
    CALL LCD_CMD
    
    MOV AH,06H
    CALL LCD_CMD
    
    RET 
ENDP LCD_INIT




;sends commands to LCD
PROC LCD_CMD
;input: AH = command code
;output: none

;save registers
    PUSH DX
    PUSH AX
;make rs=0
    MOV AL,PORTB_VAL
    AND AL,0FDH     ;En-RS-RW
    CALL OUT_B
;set out data pins
    MOV AL,AH
    CALL OUT_A
;make En=1
    MOV AL,PORTB_VAL
    OR  AL,100B     ;En-RS-RW
    CALL OUT_B
;delay 1ms
    MOV CX,50
    CALL DELAY
;make En=0
    MOV AL,PORTB_VAL
    AND AL,0FBH     ;En-RS-RW
    CALL OUT_B
;delay 1ms
    MOV CX,50
    CALL DELAY
;restore registers
    POP AX
    POP DX  
    RET
ENDP LCD_CMD




PROC LCD_CLEAR
    MOV AH,1
    CALL LCD_CMD
    RET 
ENDP LCD_CLEAR



;writes a character on current cursor position
PROC LCD_WRITE_CHAR
;input: AH
;output: none

;save registers
    PUSH AX
;set RS=1
    MOV AL,PORTB_VAL
    OR  AL,10B      ;EN-RS-RW
    CALL OUT_B
;set out the data pins
    MOV AL,AH
    CALL OUT_A
;set En=1
    MOV AL,PORTB_VAL
    OR  AL,100B     ;EN-RS-RW
    CALL OUT_B
;delay 1ms
    MOV CX,50
    CALL DELAY
;set En=0
    MOV AL,PORTB_VAL
    AND AL,0FBH     ;EN-RS-RW
    CALL OUT_B
;return
    POP AX
    RET 
ENDP LCD_WRITE_CHAR





;prints a string on current cursor position
PROC LCD_PRINTSTR
;input: SI=string address, string should end with '$'
;output: none

;save registers
    PUSH SI
    PUSH AX
;read and write character
    @LCD_PRINTSTR_LT:
        LODSB
        CMP AL,'$'
        JE @LCD_PRINTSTR_EXIT
        MOV AH,AL
        CALL LCD_WRITE_CHAR 
    JMP @LCD_PRINTSTR_LT
    
;return
    @LCD_PRINTSTR_EXIT:
    POP AX
    POP SI
    RET 
ENDP LCD_PRINTSTR




;sets the cursor
PROC LCD_SET_CUR
;input: DL=ROW, DH=COL
;       DL = 1, means upper row
;       DL = 2, means lower row
;       DH = 1-8, 1st column is 1
;output: none

;save registers
    PUSH AX
;LCD uses 0 based column index
    DEC DH
;select case    
    CMP DL,1
    JE  @ROW1
    CMP DL,2
    JE  @ROW2
    JMP @LCD_SET_CUR_END
    
;if DL==1 then
    @ROW1:
        MOV AH,80H
    JMP @LCD_SET_CUR_ENDCASE
    
;if DL==2 then
    @ROW2:
        MOV AH,0C0H
    JMP @LCD_SET_CUR_ENDCASE
        
;execute the command
    @LCD_SET_CUR_ENDCASE:   
    ADD AH,DH
    CALL LCD_CMD
    
;exit from procedure
    @LCD_SET_CUR_END:
    POP AX
    RET
ENDP LCD_SET_CUR






PROC LCD_SHOW_CUR
;input: none
;output: none
    PUSH AX
    MOV AH,0FH
    CALL LCD_CMD
    POP AX
    RET
ENDP LCD_SHOW_CUR




PROC LCD_HIDE_CUR
;input: none
;output: none
    PUSH AX
    MOV AH,0CH
    CALL LCD_CMD
    POP AX
    RET
ENDP LCD_HIDE_CUR



;sends data to output port and saves them in a variable
PROC OUT_A
;input: AL
;output: PORTA_VAL
    PUSH DX
    MOV DX,PORTA
    OUT DX,AL
    MOV PORTA_VAL,AL
    POP DX
    RET 
ENDP OUT_A


PROC OUT_B
;input: AL
;output: PORTB_VAL  
    PUSH DX
    MOV DX,PORTB
    OUT DX,AL
    MOV PORTB_VAL,AL
    POP DX
    RET
ENDP OUT_B

PROC OUT_C
;input: AL
;output: PORTC_VAL  
    PUSH DX
    MOV DX,PORTC
    OUT DX,AL
    MOV PORTC_VAL,AL
    POP DX
    RET
ENDP OUT_C



CODE ENDS ;end of CODE segment
END START ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

So how can I do this without latches?

Comment: It depends totally on how the LCD module works, which you haven't mentioned. If it contains its own data store, then no latches are required. You send fairly high-level instructions to the module, which acts pretty much like a TTY device. You might get some insight from watching Ben Eater's videos. For example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FY3zTUaykVo.

Comment: @Gene AFAIK all 20 of the address pins are multiplexed either with data or status pins. The latch is necessary to keep the address on the bus during the actual read/write. See the timing diagrams [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-mode-configuration-of-8086-microprocessor-min-mode/) fore example.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes thanks. You're right. I misunderstood the question, thinking he was asking about latches between the 8255 and display.